# Add content to <div> selector

Tags: jquery, html

Okay, so i may be asking a redudant question, but i can't seem to find the answer.

How do i, if possible, add content to a  tag with jQuery, based on current class?

```
For example adding "CODE" to div like:
<div "CODE" class="class_one"> CONTENT HERE </div>
```

Comment: "CODE" cannot appear in that position, it should be an attribute/value pair.

Comment: Do you mean `"CODE"` or something like `data-code="foobar"`? Why would you want to add `"CODE"` if you can't even access that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this.

```
$('.class_one').each(function() {
    $(this).attr('name', value); // attribute (name="value")
    $(this).data('name', value); // data (data-name="value")
});
```

Comment: The **CODE** isn't attribute in `<div "CODE"...`

Comment: Of course not. I just gave him something that will work. Maybe `"CODE"` is just an example, and he meant attributes.

Comment: Thank you! It was exactly what i was looking for. Yes, i mean attributes, and just used "CODE" as an example. So it would be something like data-source="code"

Comment: @Northhouse If you want `data-` then check my edit. Don't forget to mark answer as accepted.

Comment: @Oen44 does `.data` add a data attr? As far as I remember it doesn't add any attrs to div, but saving this data in own object

Comment: @Sergey It's the proper way. You don't have to see `data` inside DOM, right? You just want to access `data`.